# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_10_input to have shape (679, 1) but got array with shape (1, 1)

Tags: python-3.x, keras, lstm, dimensions, valueerror

I am trying to reproduce and adapt some LSTM code.

In the fitting part of the model `model.fit`, I've got the error mentioned in the title.

This is the entire traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-61-fc0772e5553b>", line 4, in <module>
    show_inner=False)])

  File "C:\Users\fassi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 952, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)

  File "C:\Users\fassi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 751, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')

  File "C:\Users\fassi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 138, in standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_10_input to have shape (679, 1) but got array with shape (1, 1)
```

And here is the command line:

```py
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=epochs, 
          validation_split=0.05, verbose=verbose, callbacks=
          [lstm_progress(), TQDMCallback(outer_description="%-16s"%"Training LSTM",
                        show_inner=False)])
```

I have cheked the shape of `X_train` : (679,1,1) and of `y_train`:(679,1), then, and just to be sure, I reshaped the `X_train` to (679,1):

```py
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1,1)
```

and I've got the following error:
`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_10_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (679, 1)`

I've tried also to do this: `X_train = X_train.reshape(1,-1,1)` in order to have a shape like this `(1, 679,1)` but I got this error:

`ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_2 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (679, 1)`

The minimal reproducible code (in case of need):

```py
O = [0.701733664614, 0.699495411782, 0.572129320819, 0.613315597684, 0.58079660603, 0.596638918579, 0.48453382119]
Ab = [datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 11, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 21, 10, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 21, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 10, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 11, 10, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 11, 14, 0)]

data = DataFrame(np.column_stack([O,Ab]),
             columns=['ndvi', 'datetime'])

decade_end = len(data)-1
decade_begin = int(decade_end - len(data)*90/100) 

data2 = data.loc[decade_begin:decade_end]

def load_data(time_series, train_perc, normalise_window, 
              decade_begin, decade_end, points=None):

    data2 = time_series.loc[decade_begin:decade_end]


    scaler = None 

    train = data2['ndvi'].values[0:-10].reshape(-1,1)
    shift_steps = 1
    train_targets = data2['ndvi'].shift(-shift_steps).values[0:-10].reshape(-1,1)
    train_reshaped = train[:, 0].reshape(len(train), 1, 1)
    x_train, y_train = train_reshaped, train_targets
    x_test = data2['ndvi'].values[:-10].reshape(-1,1)
    y_test = data2['ndvi'].values[-10:].reshape(-1,1)


    return [x_train, y_train, scaler, x_test, y_test] 

def build(layers):
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(LSTM(
        input_shape=(int(layers[1]), int(layers[0])),
        output_dim=int(layers[1]),
        return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(
        output_dim=layers[2]))
    model.add(Activation("linear"))

    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="rmsprop")
    return model


X_train, y_train, scaler = load_data(data, 1, False, 
                                         decade_begin, decade_end, points=None)[0:3]

seq_len_in  = len(X_train)
batch_size  = 40

nb_hidden   = int((2/3)*len(data))   
model = build([1, seq_len_in, nb_hidden])


X_train, y_train, scaler = load_data(data, 1, False, 
                                         decade_begin, decade_end, points=None)[0:3]
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=epochs, 
          validation_split=0.05, verbose=verbose, callbacks=
          [lstm_progress(), TQDMCallback(outer_description="%-16s"%"Training LSTM",
                        show_inner=False)])
```

Thanks in advance

NB. I have put just a sample of `data` in the miminal code. It's quite normal then if you got some other number instead of 679 in the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change 2 things: 
- the LSTM input_shape=(1,1)
- the LSTM return_sequences = False

Using your sample code:
After reshape the X_train.shape = (6,1,1)  = (samples, timesteps, features)
y_train.shape = (6,1)

So the LSTM input_shape =(1,1) not (6,1). Meaning input_shape=(timesteps, features)

Also the LSTM has return_sequences=True and thus it returns 3 dim data instead of 2 dim for the Dense layer. Which causes another error:

> Error when checking target: expected activation_2 to have 3
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (6, 1)

Meaning that for return_sequences=True the output in this case y_train should have 3 dim not 2: (6,1)
If you set return_sequences=False it works.

Using your example code:

```
import pandas as pd
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dropout, Dense, Activation


from time import daylight
import datetime
import numpy as np

O = [0.701733664614, 0.699495411782, 0.572129320819, 0.613315597684, 0.58079660603, 0.596638918579, 0.48453382119]
Ab = [datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 11, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 21, 10, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 21, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 10, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 11, 10, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 11, 14, 0)]

data = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([O,Ab]),
             columns=['ndvi', 'datetime'])

decade_end = len(data)-1
decade_begin = int(decade_end - len(data)*90/100) 

data2 = data.loc[decade_begin:decade_end]


def load_data(time_series, train_perc, normalise_window, 
              decade_begin, decade_end, points=None):

    data2 = time_series.loc[decade_begin:decade_end]
    print("data2: ",data2)

    scaler = None 

    train = data2['ndvi'].values[0:-1]#.reshape(-1,1)
    print("train: ",train)
    shift_steps = 1
    train_targets = data2['ndvi'].shift(-shift_steps).values[0:-1].reshape(-1,1)
    train_reshaped = train.reshape(len(train), 1, 1)
    x_train, y_train = train_reshaped, train_targets
    x_test = data2['ndvi'].values[:-1].reshape(-1,1)
    y_test = data2['ndvi'].values[-1:].reshape(-1,1)


    return [x_train, y_train, scaler, x_test, y_test] 

def build(layers):
    model = Sequential()
    print("layers: ", layers)
    model.add(LSTM(
        input_shape=(1, 1),
        output_dim=int(layers[0]),
        return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(
        output_dim=layers[0]))
    model.add(Activation("linear"))

    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="rmsprop")
    return model


X_train, y_train, scaler = load_data(data, 1, False, 
                                         decade_begin, decade_end, points=None)[0:3]

print(X_train)
seq_len_in  = len(X_train)
batch_size  = 1

nb_hidden   = int((2/3)*len(data))   


X_train.shape
y_train.shape

model = build([1, seq_len_in, nb_hidden])
model.summary()

X_train, y_train, scaler = load_data(data, 2, False, 
                                         decade_begin, decade_end, points=None)[0:3]
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=10, 
          validation_split=0.05, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The model is expecting data in form of (batch_size,679,1) since you are calling .fit with batch_size=batch_size

Comment: Thank you,
To reshape, I've tried This: ```
print (X_train.reshape(batch_size, X_train.shape[0], 1))``` and I've got this error:
```ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 679 into shape (40,679,1)```

Comment: what is the shape of X_train? you must have 40 vectors of shape (679,1) to be able to make a tensor of shape (40,679,1)